# Invalid package name "@" of package "@@nestjs/passport": name can only contain URL-friendly characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server, nestjs

Creates a Module Federation applcation, API server, but when I running command npm install I am getting error. My node version is `v16.17.1` and npm version is `8.19.2`

```
╰─ npx create-mf-app                                                                                              ─╯
? Pick the name of your app: server
? Project Type: API Server
? Port number: 8080
? Template: nestjs-auth
Your 'server' project is ready to go.
```

Next steps:

▶️ cd server
▶️ npm install
▶️ npm start

Error:

```
npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
npm ERR! Invalid package name "@" of package "@@nestjs/passport": name can only contain URL-friendly characters.
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@": "nestjs/passport",
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^8.0.1",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/serve-static": "^2.2.2",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "passport": "^0.5.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/passport-local": "^1.0.34",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.28.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.28.2",
    "eslint": "^7.30.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.6",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.10.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

Comment: At first glance it look like "@": "nestjs/passport", should not be there. But after deleting it I am getting a different error while running npm start. I can see there are developers who posted the same error but did not get any solution.

Comment: just drop that `@` entry and the lock file. Run `npm install`. Got an error? share it with us then.

Comment: @MicaelLevi Drop @ form which line ?

Comment: If I remove this line ("@": "nestjs/passport") I am getting Error: "ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\React-applications\microFrontEnd\youtube\server\public\index.html'"

Comment: Its working now, I removed the @ entry and removed the package-lock.json and run npm install.

Answer (score 0):

So as Micael Levi suggested I removed the  `"@": "nestjs/passport",` entry from package.json and deleted package-lock.json file and run command `npm install`. It resolved the error.